# Swift initializer with different name than class?

Tags: swift

I think the answer is "don't do that", but here goes... Consider:

```
class Enemy {
   var name: String
   var type: Int
   init(ofType: Int) {
       type=ofType
   }
}
```

I have two types of enemies, friends=0 and closeFriends=1. One's enemies might switch between these at any time. So:

```
var newEnemy = Enemy(ofType:.closeFriend)
newEnemy.name = "Bob"
```

and perhaps at some time in the future:

```
newEnemy.type = .friend
```

But I find this syntax somewhat opaque. For the same reason that it's better to use an `enum` instead of an `Int`, your intentions are much more clear if you make new objects that directly represent their type, perhaps:

```
var newEnemy = CloseFriend(withName:"Bob")
```

Normally this requires subclassing Friend and CloseFriend, but then one cannot simply turn a Friend into a CloseFriend.

`typealias` seems like it might be a solution, I could alias Enemy to Friend and CloseFriend. But that doesn't add a new init that sets the `type` based on the alias. For instance, CloseFriend() should set the type to 1 without it having to be specified. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You should look into the Factory Method design pattern, basically you have a separate static function for each type of enemy you want to create.

Comment: It seems to me like an enemy and a friend would have very different behaviour as they relate to your own character. I suspect that if you did model `Enemy` and `Friend` within a single type, you would end up with a whole bunch of switch cases within every method, doing one thing for friends, and another for enemies. That's a very strong indication that you need to split off your model into two different types, preferably implementing the same protocol

Comment: @Alexander - the names are a play on the statement that you keep your enemies close and your friends closer. Let us call them A, B and C then, B and C are both A's and differ only in a single value.

Comment: There's at least 3 solution "avenues" I can think of here: multiple types under a common superclass or protocol, an enum holding one of multiple values, or in-place mutation of a single object. Which one is most appropriate is a pretty nuanced decision which doesn't lend itself well to abstract examples. Do you have a particular use-case in mind, that spurred you into writing this question?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather simple to do using a function but I would really advise against it:

```
class Enemy {
    enum EnemyType: Int {
        case friend
        case closeFriend
    }

    var name: String
    var type: EnemyType

    init(type: EnemyType, name: String = "") {
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
    }
}

// let's make a function that looks like creating new object
func CloseFriend(name: String) -> Enemy {
    return Enemy(type: .closeFriend, name: name)
}
```

Such "smart" things completely destroy the readability of your code. There is nothing more readable than writing:

```
Enemy(type: .closeFriend, name: "Bob")
```

There is no reason to save a few letters of code.

Sure, you could create a factory function

```
extension Enemy {
    static func closeFriend(name: String) -> Enemy {
        return Enemy(type: .closeFriend, name: name)
    }
}
```

but is it really better to call:

```
Enemy.closeFriend(name: "Bob")
```

vs

```
Enemy(type: .closeFriend, name: "Bob")
```

?

Comment: Comparing the last two I see no improvement in syntax. Yet I still see a significant improvement in the case of Friend().

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the same person becomes changes from a friend to a close friend, it makes perfect sense to reuse the same instance. Just like it would happen in the real life, when relationships between people change (you don't get someone's clone if that person starts hating you and wants to destroy you).

What you could improve, architecturally speaking, is to merge the "skills" and the type of the enemy. E.g.:

```swift
class Enemy {
    var name: String
    var traits: Traits

    enum Traits {
        case friend(FriendTraits)
        case closeFriend(CloseFriendTraits)
    }

    struct FriendTraits { ... }
    struct CloseFriendTraits { ... }
}
```

This way you can simply change the type, while preserving the other attributes (and if you're developing a game the other attributes might be important).

Comment: The first sentence is precisely what I am trying to get at. I have a big array of object that are mutating all the time. There's no real technical issue here, but the readability of the code would be greatly improved if one could create the instances of the subtypes.